# javafx stage seems to have invisible width

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

So I’m learning how to use JavaFx and am tasting out a simply blank window to get started and I encountered a Strang problem. In the code you can see that the position of the stage is 0:0 but as you can see in the screenshot while the Y position is correct the X position is off by a little. I managed to figure out that the offset is about 7 pixels. Meaning that if I type -7 for the X position it will be right in the corner as intended but typing in 0 gives me this strange result.

Here is my code

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FxTest extends Application {

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            
    //set up Stage Object
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World 2");  
    primaryStage.setX(0);
    primaryStage.setY(0);
    primaryStage.setWidth(400);
    primaryStage.setHeight(400);
    primaryStage.show();    
    
}// end start method


public static void main(String[] args) {
            
    launch();
                    
}//end of main method
```

}//end class FxTest

Here is a screenshot of were the Stage window ends up
[image]

also I'm using eclipse IDE

Comment: You should check your screen resolution using `javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D` to check if the width is good: `Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds(); System.out.println(screenBounds);`

Comment: i get Rectangle2D [minX = 0.0, minY=0.0, maxX=1920.0, maxY=1080.0, width=1920.0, height=1080.0] which is what I expected. still don't help me with my problem.

Comment: Is it the same thing when you replace `getBounds()` by `getVisualBounds()`? (screen resolution without Windows bars and borders)

Comment: I get Rectangle2D [minX = 0.0, minY=0.0, maxX=1920.0, maxY=1040.0, width=1920.0, height=1040.0]
The -40 to the Y is obviously the taskbar of windows but the again the problem is in the X axis not the Y axis.